# c++ OpenCV capture easycap usb cam

Tags: c++, opencv, usb, video-capture

I am trying to get video stream from analog camera connected to usb easycap - in OpenCV C++.

using MATLAB, I can get stream the same approach like for laptop webcam (with changing the index from 1 to 2).

with OpenCV, I can get stream from laptop webcam with index 0.
but when I am trying to get with the camera connected to the easycap (using index 1) , the laptop crashes and get blue screen.

Anyone have done this before?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the (minimal) code that doesn't work? You might also be interested in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22019064/1601291): it seems very similar.

Comment: can you confirm that the bluescreen crash appears when videocap.release is called? although I didnt manage to get any legal image, neither with opencv nor with directshow... only some small program that is delivered with the stk1160 drivers gives images for me... probably I'll try some more expensive grabbers now, but unsure which one to get. Should work with opencv...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work on the same device and I also have some BSOD with it.

Do you plug it with the USB extension provided ? If yes, try don't use it.

If your problem is still hapening, it's probably because like me, you use a low quality chinese fake EasyCap. I bought a real one and I haven't problems anymore

If you want to keep your device, you can use it with [VideoCapture](http://videocapture.sourceforge.net/) in python, it works very well and there is no more BSOD

Comment: It is a chinese one , and maybe low quality . but on the other hand, I can get stream using MATLAB - so It's still HW problem , or OpenCV support?

Comment: I've the same. The BSOD depend of the driver used to catch the stream. With DirectShow capture it works, also MATLAB, VideoCapture (Python), but not with OpenCv.

Look at this librairie : [DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375468(v=vs.85).aspx)

.On the other hand, you can buy a good quality EazCap and it will also work with OpenCv

Comment: No - do you got a solution?

Comment: I already give you the solution before :

With DirectShow capture it works, also MATLAB, VideoCapture (Python), but not with OpenCv. Look at this librairie : DirectShow .On the other hand, you can buy a good quality EazCap and it will also work with OpenCv

Comment: Hi , you said : "with DirectShow it works"! how can I use DirectShow in  C++ OpenCV code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Linux. I tested my code with a fake EasyCAP in windows and I got many BSOD then I built and executed the same code in Linux and it worked.
Linux is driver friendly.