# OpenCV VideoCapture retrieve Is not working

Tags: java, opencv, video-capture

I am attempting to capture frames from a webcam. The webcam appears to be opening correctly however the `retrieve()` and `read()` statements always return `false`.

```
Mat frame1 = new Mat();

VideoCapture cap1 = new VideoCapture(0);

try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(cap1.isOpened());

System.out.println(cap1.read(frame1));
```

Output:

```
True 
False
```

Comment: What happens if you use the operator `>>` instead of `read` to read the frames? `cv::Mat temp;` `cap1 >> temp;`

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22023536/2436175) might have related information.

Comment: can you try `for(int i=0; i<500; ++i) System.out.println(cap1.read(frame1));` ? maybe your devices needs some time until it produces legal images.