# C++: OpenCV2.4.11(!) access to webcam parameters

Tags: c++, opencv, directshow, webcam-capture

This is a direct follow-up of the last question I asked which was aptly named "C++: OpenCV2.3.1(!) access to webcam parameters" and where I was told to install OpenCV2.4.11 instead (OpenCV3.0 did not work)... which I did. And yes, most of this text is an exact copy&paste of the last thread since my problem hasn't actually vanished...

Again, I've searched here, on other forums (Google, OpenCV etc), looked at the code of the videoInput library, the different header files and especially OpenCV's highgui_c.h and still seem to be unable to find an answer to this very simple question:

**How do I change exposure and gain (or, to be general, any webcam property) in my Logitech C310 webcam with OpenCV2.4.11 the same way I was able to with OpenCV2.1.0? (using Win7 64-bit, Visual Studio 10)**

*EDIT: This has been solved. I do not know how but when I tested my code this morning it was able to report and set the exposure using VideoCapture and the set/get method.*

There's the nice and easy VideoCapture get and set method, I know, similar to the videoInput's [Set/Get]VideoSetting[Camera/Filter] functions. **Here's my short example in OpenCV2.4.11 that doesn't work:**

*EDIT: It does work now. What I don't understand is that the values of several properties are reported as **-8.58993E+008** (namely hue, monocrome, gamma, temperature, zoom, focus, pan, tilt, roll and iris) and that property 6 (fourcc) is **-4.66163E+008**. I know I don't have these features on my webcam but all other unimplemented features report -1.*

```
int __stdcall WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, char* CmdArgs, int CmdShow) {
    int device0 = 0;
    VideoCapture VC(device0);
    if(!VC.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;
    ostringstream oss;
    double CamProp;
    for(int i=-4; i<27; i++) {
        CamProp = VC.get(i);
        Sleep(5);
        oss << "Item " << i << ": " << CamProp << "\n";
    }

    MessageBox(NULL, oss.str().c_str(), "Webcam Values", MB_OK);

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles, it runs, it accesses the webcam alright (and even shows a picture with imshow if I add it to the code)  but it only opens a nice window saying this:
Item -4: 0
Item -3: 0
Item -2: 0
...
Item 2: 0
**Item 3: 640

Item 4: 480**
Item 5: 0
...
Item 25: 0
Item 26: 0

*EDIT: See above, this works now. I get values for all supported parameters like exposure, gain, sharpness, brightness, contrast and so on. Perhaps I was still linking to the 2.3.1 libraries or whatever.*

The point is: This was all perfectly settable with this camera under OpenCV 2.1.0 using videoInput. I had a running application doing its own lighting instead of using the Logitech functions (RightLight, Auto Exposure, Auto Whitebalance). Now setting and getting the parameters has been integrated into OpenCV highgui for quite a while but with a strongly reduced feature list (no requesting of parameter ranges, Min/Max/Stepwidth..., no setting of auto exposure, RightLight and similar stuff) and for some reason it's incompatible with my Logitech webcam. I can report the resolution but nothing else.

**EDIT: I still miss the Min, Max, Step, Auto/Manual features of videoInput. I can set a value but I don't know whether it's allowed.**

The videoInput code is now merged into OpenCV's code in the file cap_dshow.cpp but I can't find a header file that declares the videoInput class and simply using my old code doesn't work. So I have a cpp file which contains all functions I need and which I know did the job for me a while back but which I can't access now. Any clues on how to do that? Has anyone accessed and changed camera parameters in OpenCV2.4.11 using the videoInput/DirectShow interface?

*EDIT: Seems this has happened now in a working way, unlike 2.3.1. No direct interaction with videoInput seems to be needed. However it would be nice to have it for the aforementioned reasons.*

There's also the funny problem that using e.g.

```
VideoCapture cam(0)
```

addresses exactly the same camera as

```
VideoCapture cam(1)
```

or

```
VideoCapture cam(any integer value)
```

which seems odd to me and hints in the same direction - that CV's VideoCapture does not work properly for me. A similar problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019064/unable-to-read-frames-from-videocapture-from-secondary-webcam-with-opencv) but I also tried the code with a Sleep(1000) after opening the capture - without success.

*EDIT: This is also working correctly now. I get my webcam with (0) and and error with (1) which is absolutely OK.*