# OpenCV Videocapture SOMETIMES fail

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture

Hello (I am working with OpenCV 2.4.13 on Windows 8 with Qt5.7 MinGW),

I have a really weird problem with OpenCV. I try to grab video frames in a thread. It works very well all the time in release mode. In order to deploy my program, I copied the .exe in a folder and included all the dependencies with the .exe. I then built an installer with NSIS.

On several computers, the program works all the time. However, on two computers (Win 8 and Win 7),the videocapture sometimes fail. Sometimes I start the program and everything is fine. Other times, I start the program and all the frames are empty. In the latter case, the capture.open(0) returns 1 which is ok, but the frames are empty.

I tried this: When I get 10 empty frames, I release the video capture, reopen the camera and try to grab frame. But it does not work, the frames are always empty.

The point in common with these two computers is that they have AVG. There are more chances for the capture to fail when AVG is on. There is also more chances for the capture to fail when I run the program as an administrator.

I am working with OpenCV 2.4.13 on Windows 8 with Qt5.7 MinGW.
Here is an exerpt of my code.

```
cv::VideoCapture capture; 
int test1=capture.open(0); // This returns 1 so it's ok. 
while(test1)
{ 
   capture >> frame;   
   if (!frame.empty())
   {
     //code here (when it fails it does not enter here)
   }
   else
   {
     //code here (when it fails it does enter here)
   }
}
```

Any ideas ????

Thank you so much,

Alex

edit: code:

```
if (m_ValidControl == 1)
{
    int test1=capture.open(0);

  if (test1==1)
  {
    CountNoCam = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++)
    {
        capture >> frame;

        if (!frame.empty())
        {
            cv::Mat frametemp1;
            cv::resize(frame, frametemp1, cv::Size(640, 480), 0, 0);
            std::shared_ptr<cv::Mat> frameshow = std::make_shared<cv::Mat>(cv::Mat());
            frametemp1.copyTo(*frameshow);
            (p_blackboard->get_frameshow())->store(frameshow);//storedone
        }
        else //when it fails it enters here each time
        {
            CountNoCam++;
            if (CountNoCam > 100)
                CountNoCam = 100;

            if (CountNoCam > 10)
            {
                std::shared_ptr<int> stop = std::make_shared<int>(1);
                p_blackboard->get_stopthreads()->store(stop);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
  }
}

}
```

Comment: `if (!frame.empty())` is checking if the frame is not empty.`if (frame.empty())` checks if the frame is empty.

Comment: I know, thank you. (!frame.empty()) does not pass, it goes in the else.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019064/unable-to-read-frames-from-videocapture-from-secondary-webcam-with-opencv?rq=1 maybe it will help.

Comment: Thank you. In their case, it was only the first frame that was empty because the camera was not ready. This happens sometimes. But in my case, it's all the frames in the while loop, not just the first.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.8/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html is another thing I came across.

Comment: Also, there is something weird. When I run the program from the release folder (with the dll included) it works 100% of the time (I tried more than a hundred times).
However, if I copy all the files to another folder, this is when the videocapture sometimes fail (50% of the time).

Comment: hmm sounds kind of like undefined behavior, to me.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: ok I get what you mean. But the videocapture code is textbook. I will check in detail but I don't see what it could be...
Could it be because my videocapture is in a thread ?

Comment: well the program base itself runs on a thread. I am not sure if the video capture runs on a separate thread or not. It is unlikely the problem, though, as it seems to have a problem with directories. What does your code actually look like?

Comment: I included the code in the main question. Thanks.

Comment: You will think that I'm crazy but:
The name of my exe is : "AssistCamerBetaV0R1.exe".  (it fails 50% of the time)
I changed it to "acbeta.exe" and when I launch it, it never fails (over 30 trials).
I then tried for fun "assistcamerabetavor1.exe", "assistcamerabetaputr.exe" but they were sometimes failing.
I tried a very long name such as "assistcamerabetaakldjfdkdfasdf.exe" and it never failed.
I know it may sound crazy or just luck but it really seems to work.
Would you have a logical explanation for this ?

Comment: Maybe some scraps were being left over and caused fails. Maybe restarting the computer would also increase success the same way renaming the file did.

Comment: Yes. It's just weird that some other names such as "assistcamerabetaputr.exe" also failed...
Well, I will see if the problem comes back. Thank you so much for your help !!