# Tensorflow: Mac OS camera switched on but video not visible on screen

Tags: python, macos, opencv, tensorflow, camera

For a current project, I am trying to set up a video recognition program leveraging TensorFlow 2 and OpenCV (Mac OS Catalina).

When running the below script with Python 3 through terminal or via Jupyter, the green "wecam light" is indicating that the camera is switched on and no error messages appear. However, there is not video image/window showing on my screen. I have tried various solutions, including adding camera screen frame data, none of which worked.

Does anyone know a smart tweak to make the camera image/window visible?

```
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile
import cv2

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

# Define the video stream
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # Change only if you have more than one webcams

# What model to download.
# Models can bee found here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md
MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_inception_v2_coco_2017_11_17'
MODEL_FILE = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'

# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
PATH_TO_CKPT = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('data', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')

# Number of classes to detect
NUM_CLASSES = 90

# Download Model
opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
opener.retrieve(DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_FILE, MODEL_FILE)
tar_file = tarfile.open(MODEL_FILE)
for file in tar_file.getmembers():
    file_name = os.path.basename(file.name)
    if 'frozen_inference_graph.pb' in file_name:
        tar_file.extract(file, os.getcwd())


# Load a (frozen) Tensorflow model into memory.
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')


# Loading label map
# Label maps map indices to category names, so that when our convolution network predicts `5`, we know that this corresponds to `airplane`.  Here we use internal utility functions, but anything that returns a dictionary mapping integers to appropriate string labels would be fine
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(
    label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)


# Helper code
def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
    (im_width, im_height) = image.size
    return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(
        (im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)


# Detection
with detection_graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
        while True:

            # Read frame from camera
            ret, image_np = cap.read()
            # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
            image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
            # Extract image tensor
            image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
            # Extract detection boxes
            boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
            # Extract detection scores
            scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
            # Extract detection classes
            classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
            # Extract number of detectionsd
            num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name(
                'num_detections:0')
            # Actual detection.
            (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
                [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
                feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
            # Visualization of the results of a detection.
            vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                image_np,
                np.squeeze(boxes),
                np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
                np.squeeze(scores),
                category_index,
                use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                line_thickness=8)

            # Display output
            cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(image_np, (800, 600)))

            if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                break
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing **-1 or 1** as the device index of the `VideoCapture`? Just in case you haven't tried it yet.

But

First of all, you should know where it went wrong. We should verify if the system reads the frames properly.
You can try implementing this to test if your camera is running and being read properly:

```
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera")
    exit()
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # if frame is read correctly ret is True
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break
    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv.imshow('frame', gray)
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

`cap.read()` returns a bool (True/False). If the frame is read correctly, it will be **True**. So you can check for the end of the video by checking this returned value.

Sometimes, `cap` may not have initialized the capture. In that case, this code shows an **error**. You can check whether it is initialized or not by the method `cap.isOpened()`. If it is True, OK. Otherwise open it using `cap.open()`.

with this, it will help you and us to determine what part has gone wrong and can suggest furthermore solutions.
After this, if the test shows no error, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019064/unable-to-read-frames-from-videocapture-from-secondary-webcam-with-opencv) will be a little bit related.
You can check it out.

Provide us the result from this so we can inspect furthermore.

Comment: Yup I had tried that - it did not work unfortunately. I assume I have to re-install my operating system to make sure the camera is fully supported. Thanks anyways for your efforts, I highly appreciate it.